# Can't make my HTTP.GET request with Flutter work properly: OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I'm kinda new to Flutter. What's wrong with my request ?

Some friend of mine configured a SAP web service and the ***_kAuth*** you'll read in the code is the token needed that is defined this way:

```
static const _kAuth = "Basic $tokenhiddenforprivacy=";
```

What I'm getting:

1. Error : Generic Error(screenshot below). Is it only a problem with a hopefully wrong token? is it a problem with my code since it deals with a Null-Safe error?
2. Error: Right after the first error I got this **OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7**

Main is:

```
class CredentialsRecoveryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CredentialsRecoveryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/CredentialsRecoveryPage';

  @override
  _CredentialsRecoveryPageState createState() =>
      _CredentialsRecoveryPageState();
}

class _CredentialsRecoveryPageState extends State<CredentialsRecoveryPage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _alreadyTapped = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 30),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Seems like you forgot something...",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text("We need your mail",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        // fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value) => _validateMail(value!),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                      decoration: mailInputDecoration(context),
                      onSaved: (value) => _emailController.text = value!),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Text("The mail will be delivered within 10 minutes",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10,
                        // fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _alreadyTapped,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () => _sendCredentialRequest(context),
                            child: Icon(LineIcons.paperPlane,
                                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String? _validateMail(String mail) {
    if (_emailController.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Mail field cant\'t be empty';
    } else if (!_emailController.text.toUpperCase().contains("@")) {
      return 'Mail is not valid';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> _sendCredentialRequest(BuildContext ctx) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      startLoadingSpinner(ctx);
      try {
        var resp =
            await NetworkManager().getForCredentials(_emailController.text);
        if (resp.statusCode >= 200 && resp.statusCode <= 300) {
          var message = SapReturnMessage.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body));
          Navigator.pop(ctx);
          setState(() {
            _alreadyTapped = false;
          });
          return message.returnSnackByMessage(ctx);
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(ctx);
          SnackBarMessage.genericError(ctx, "Something went wrong!");
        }
      } catch (onError) {
        Navigator.pop(ctx);
        SnackBarMessage.genericError(ctx, onError.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my **networkManager.dart** I have this **getForCredentials** class :

```
Future<http.Response> getForCredentials(String mail) async {
    var url =
        "http://mylinkhiddenforprivacy";

    return await http
        .get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
          "Authorization": _kAuth,
          "Accept": "application/json",
        })
        .then((response) {
          return response;
        })
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 20))
        .catchError((onError) {
          print(onError.toString());
        });
  }
```

And this is the output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHNs.png)

Comment: I guess it's because you're not returning anything inside catchError in getForCredentials() function

Comment: I added " return http.Response('', 500);" as you suggested and I correctly get a "Something went wrong!" Snackbar message as expected from "credentialRecoveryPage.dart" code, so can we assume the problem with server connection may be the wrong token only?

Comment: You can a give second arg to catchError as 'stacktrace'. print both args to the console to see the actual error.

Comment: And if you're not sure about the token test is using Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

### I found the answer

---

##### I'll sum up the steps i went through so that you can do the same up untill one of them will help you out

---

@Xoltawn advice was good to start, in order to avoid the error. So I added as suggested:

```
return http.Response("", 500);
```

Actually the real problem was another, similar to those you find on the web according to which (typically): "OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7"

I remind you I needed to make an http get request to a SAP Web Service not configured by myself, I only had the url and the token --> "Basic $token" <--
And my code was:

```
var url = Uri.parse(
        "myurl");

    return await http
        .get(url, headers: {
          "authorization": "Basic $mytoken",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        })
```

Here started my problems. Everyone on web wrote about connection issues so they suggested to add to both main and debug manifest files:

1. STEP

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Problem wasn't fixed so I read someone fixed changing package so:

2. STEP

Move from HTTP to DIO [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

In case you don't fix try:

3. STEP

Use some **Online API Testing Tool** like [reqbin](https://reqbin.com/) or Postman (I used reqbin which I found faster and easier to make a fast GET request just using URL and CUSTOM authorization using the "Basic $token" like the one I had) so that you're sure your URL and TOKEN are properly working and the real problem is Flutter and/or packages and/or sintax errors

In case you don't fix try:

4. STEP

I figured It out the errors deals with "hostname" so actually my URL is something like http: // examplewithoutwww.com:port /.... so the normal HTTP GET or DIO GET couldn't work properly, It was something about DNS misconfigured maybe. So I tried to change the url using Google's so something like:

```
var url = Uri.parse(
        "http://www.google.com");

    return await http
        .get(url, headers: {
          "authorization": "Basic $mytoken",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        })
        .then((response) {
          return response;
        })
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 20))
        .catchError((onError) {
          print(onError.toString());
          return http.Response("", 500);
        });
  }
```

Yet still same error. So the problem wasn't yet me but I found it --> [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android) *Starting with Android API 28 and iOS 9, these platforms disable insecure HTTP connections by default.*
This is the first 50% of the solution

5. STEP

Add to your Manifest files :

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

So now the HTTP GET from Google worked! But not yet from my **http://examplewithoutwww.com:port/....** so eventually the solution was understand which IP was my host, in my case something like **http://212.29.432.121/**

So the last 2 steps to fix it are:

6. STEP

Go to your EMULATOR Settings (the 3 dots bottom-right your virtual android phone --> Settings --> Proxy) and set your hostname and port manually to (in my case) **http://212.29.432.121/** and the PORT I had in the original Url.

7. STEP

Eventually make your URL something like:

**http://IP/....**, remember **WITHOUT** the port in the Url!

Thanks for the attention, Enjoy!